# Trying to Pass data from Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm new in Android Development here i'm trying to pass data from Activity to Fragment
"gameid" <-- i want to pass this data from Activity to Fragment
im using this code which is not working anyone tell me whats wrong in this code !!!!

> Activity Class

```
    public CardView matchCard;
    ImageView gamebanner;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager2 pager2;
    bettingpage_tabviewer adapter;

    private ArrayList<MatchModel> gList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_betting_page);


        String gameid = getIntent().getStringExtra(GAME_ID);
        String banner = getIntent().getStringExtra(BANNER);


        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("gameId", gameid);
        // set Fragmentclass Arguments
        matchtab fragobj = new matchtab();
        fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

        gamebanner = findViewById(R.id.gamebanner);
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.bettingtabs);
        pager2 = findViewById(R.id.bettingpagetab);


        Glide.with(this).load(banner).into(gamebanner);



        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        final matchtab myFragment = new matchtab();
        adapter = new bettingpage_tabviewer(fm, getLifecycle());
        pager2.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Match Tab"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Result Tab"));

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                pager2.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });


        pager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(position));
            }
        });

 }
}
```

> Fragment Class

want to show "gameid" data in TextView named "demo"

```
public class matchtab extends Fragment {


    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "gameId";


    private String gameId;


    RecyclerView matachrecyclerview;

    private MyAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Model> gList;


    public matchtab() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static matchtab newInstance(String  gameId) {
        matchtab fragment = new matchtab();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("gameId", gameId);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
//
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            gameId = this.getArguments().getString("gameId");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_matchtab, container, false);

        TextView demo;

        demo = v.findViewById(R.id.demotxt);

        demo.setText(gameId);





        // Recycler View
        matachrecyclerview = v.findViewById(R.id.matchrecyclerview);
        gList = new ArrayList<>();
         FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference root = db.getReference("Match").child("game1");
        root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Model model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Model.class);
                    gList.add( new Model(model.title,model.amt));

                    Log.i("THE_CURRENT_USER:::", model.toString());
                }
                LinearLayoutManager im = new LinearLayoutManager((getContext()));
                matachrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(im);
                adapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(),gList);
                matachrecyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
        return v;}

}
```

This Code is not working please tell me what's wrong in this code

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use constructor in fragment, remove it. You're directly passing the parameters to fragment with bundle.put in activity, no need for newinstance in fragment then. Try to remove default constructor and newinstance and try again.

Answer (score 0):

dude you created two instances of fragment and set the arguments to 1 but use 2 without arguments

1. Use first capital letter in class name and some useful names)
2. try to do

in your fragment:

```
    public static MyFragment newInstance(String gameId) {
        MyFragment fragment  = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("gameId", gameId);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

in your activity:

```
MyFragment.newInstance(gameId)
```

Comment: this are the changes ive done [Activity](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/esports-f0b71.appspot.com/o/change1.png?alt=media&token=ea21b06e-c4df-4d97-9e7d-1958d38016ec) [Fragment](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/esports-f0b71.appspot.com/o/Screenshot%202021-05-13%20222401.png?alt=media&token=631be93d-2173-4222-9074-49bab6bc57bd) but still not working

Comment: I didn't see where you place your fragments in activity, update your code snippet and check your adapter